# Appearance from PHP or jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

First, sorry for my English, you can correct me in that area too :)

I know that i can replace text in html with `<?=$var?>` for example. Also, i can do it through ajax. I use $.ajax to get data in JSON format, than inside jquery i'm changing appearance of my web app.

This is example of getting data, and inside this function i'm calling $.View function where apperance is changing.

```
$.Model = function(route, data){
    $.ajax({
        url: "php/books.php?"+route,
        type: "POST",
        data: {data: data}
    }).done(function(response){
        var resp = JSON.parse(response);
        $.View(route, resp, data);
    }).fail(function(msg){
        console.log('something is wrong');
    });
   });
};
```

Example of $.View function

```
$.View = function(route, response, data){
    if(route==='menuItem'){
        var studio='';
        $.each(response, function(index, value){
          studio += '<button id='+value['STUDIJI_ID']+' class="btn btn-primary studio_button">'+value['STUDIO']+'</button>';
        });
        $(studio).appendTo(".here");
    }
};
```

So, my question is, what is the best approach for such things? Embed PHP variable to html or do it through jQuery on described way? Or, something third?

Thank you for your time and help.

Comment: if you need ajax do it with ajax else do it with  php

Comment: It is purely based on you and your application. If some where you need ajax then you have to use ajax. You can't do that by php. In the backend data fetch and database connection those are by php. It is depend that your application need a normal php post method or ajax post method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your requirements.

If you know everything on page creation, insert the values with php.
If you wnat to update only parts of your page after page is loaded, do it with ajax.